# What are the longest built-in functions names ever?

Tags: function, naming

I'm sick and tired of typing `mysql_real_escape_string()` due to its extreme length, Wondering if there is more long built-in function names out there?

Comment: I would argue that you might consider upgrading your tools if you have to type it out every time. I would also argue that verbose naming is the best thing you can do for any code that involves more than one developer.

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer, but is there an IDE for PHP that has "intellisense" or "code completion", where you start typing out the first few characters of a built in function, and the IDE completes it?

Comment: There are a number of IDE's which supports auto-completion. Notepad++, Netbeans to name a few

Comment: I've made a list here of the TOP10: https://github.com/CodeBrauer/LongestPHP

Answer (score 8):

I don't know of longer function names in PHP, but in .Net, you got
the `GetTextEffectCharacterIndexFromTextSourceCharacterIndex` method of `System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextSource`.

But you could use an editor with code completion to keep you from typing. Or even better: use a wrapper class for your MySQL connectivity. This will save you from having to type long function names, reduces the risk of security issues (forgetting to call `mysql_real_escape_string` or calling it incorrectly), and it will save you lots of migrating if you ever need to shift to another database or need to go using mysqli.

Answer (score 2):

You can check them out [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).

You could get an editor which supports auto-completion.

Comment: +1 for auto-completion. Speaks to the heart of the problem.